# How to populate a listview between two dates vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, populate

I am writing a code that filters the listview data between two selected dates. The code is not working, i am not finding a way to make it work in a listview, although it works on a datagrid.

```
listavalor.Items.Clear()
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
Dim coiso As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM custospessoais WHERE CUS_DATA BETWEEN '" &
     Format(datapicker1.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy") & "' AND '" &
     Format(datapicker2.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy") & "' CUS_ID;")
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(coiso)
da.Fill(dt)
Dim coluna As DataRow
For Each coluna In dt.Rows
    listavalor.Items.Add(coluna.Item(0))
    listavalor.Items(listavalor.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(coluna.Item(1))
    listavalor.Items(listavalor.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(coluna.Item(2))
    listavalor.Items(listavalor.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(coluna.Item(3))
Next
```

Comment: Questions on SO need to be specific. Either your issue is with getting the right data querying the database or it is with populating the ListView with the data you get. The two are unrelated. You need to work out where the issue is and ask the question you actually need answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a date or datetime type in the DB, not a text type, to store dates.
2. Use command parameters. This makes the code immune to formatting problems and SQL injection.
3. If you don't follow the advice from 1. and 2., at least use the inverse date format yyyy-MM-dd.

   1. If the date is stored as text it still sorts and compares right.
   2. You don't have a problem US-style dates MM-dd-yyyy.

See also: [MySQL Data Types](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-data-types.aspx/)

Comment: If i use the dd-MM-yyyy format as text it won't compare?

Comment: If the column is of a date type (DATE or DATETIME) it will compare correctly, assuming that there is no US-date versus almost-everybody-else-date problem. If it is a text (VARCHAR) column, it will not compare correctly, because it will first compare by day, then by month and lastly by year. For the order to be correct it must be compared by year, then month and finally by day. Also day and month must always have two digits.

Comment: thanks a lot, i solved my problem, swiching to date type was the right call.